# What could be a practical application of double summation with two variables?

Tags: statistics

I understand the theoretical concept of double summation, but struggle to see where it could be applied with 2 variables. E.g. (an example quoted in my course):

$\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{i=0}^n  (x_i y_j)$

Single variable double sums like these make more sense to me

$\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{i=0}^n  x_{ij}$

I could still come up with a practical application for a double-indexed variable but not when a second variable comes into play.

Can anyone give me some more insight as to how this has a useful purpose ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. When particles interact through the Coulomb or gravitational potential, their distribution $f_N = f_N(x_1, v_1,\dots,x_N,v_N)$ follows the Liouville equation
$$
\partial f_N + \sum_{k=1}^N v_k\cdot\nabla_{x_k} f_N = C \sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{j\neq k}\frac{x_k-x_j}{|x_k-x_j|^3} \cdot \nabla_{v_k}f_N.
$$
The double sum appears because for each particle, the force corresponds to the sum exerted by all the other particles.